# Using JSOUP to Login Post Form

Tags: java, post, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to use the Java jsoup library to login to https://www.5dimes.eu/ via a login post form. I can't figure out what is wrong with my code but I think it has something to do with how I am accounting for a hidden field in the form named "ioBB".

Here is my current code:

```
public class TestLogin5Dimes {
private static Document d;

private static String ioBB = "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";

public static void main(String[] args){
    //With this you login and a session is created
    try{


           Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("https://www.5dimes.eu/")
                   .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                   .execute();

                  Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.5dimes.eu/LoginVerify.Asp")
                   .data("cookieexists", "false")
                   .data("customerID", "user123")
                   .data("password", "password123")
                   .data("goto","Sportsbook Main")
                   .data("ioBB", ioBB)
                   .data("submit1", "login")
                   .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                   .post();
                  System.out.println(document);

    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Failed");
    }
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as I've been banging my head trying to figure this out for the past day.

Comment: For starters, `ioBB` is not static; exactly to counter what you are trying to do.

Comment: Oh. So would a workaround be to first fetch the document, parse out the ioBB string and then use that value to login similar to how I'm trying now?

Comment: The value is specifically made for that one request, so most likely not. It's a black box so to speak. Try viewing the source code on the main website, you can see this `// io_bbout_element_id should refer to the hidden field in your form that contains the blackbox`.

Comment: Figured out which script is generating this string. Still no clue how I would get the value if its auto-generated per request. Damn

Comment: can you please update the page document ?